# VoIP phone recommendation with good speakerphone under $300

Tags: voip

I'm looking for about a dozen VoIP phones for a small office. Criteria:

- Not Polycom (terrible support)
- Under $300 USD
- Good speakerphone quality

Any brands/models you would recommend based on your experience?

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're using Grandstream products - the speakerphone is OK, they're dirt cheap, and my users have been pretty pleased with them.  You can also get excellent Cisco phones under $300.

If you haven't looked there yet I would suggest checking out [voipsupply.com](http://www.voipsupply.com/) -- their prices are decent and the user reviews are usually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going with just SIP phones?  Either way I would recommend any Cisco phone.  I have personally dealt with 7971G-GE phones and they sound amazing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind used phones, you can get Cisco 7940's for well under 300$/ea off of ebay.

They may be old and not as feature rich as some of the newer models, but they are great phones.

Actually It looks like the 794x series is about 250$ new now.